# How to train this Tensorflow with Spring-Boot project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tensorflow, training-data

I have a Tensorflow project that runs a trained system.
I want to convert this trained system in a system that can train every time the result is not on the system.
Is an image-recognition project.

The system classify this way:

```
@Override
public O classify(I input) {
    Assert.notNull(model, "Classifier is not initialized");
    log.trace("Started image processing");
    try (Session session = new Session(model);
    Tensor<T> inputTensor = getInputTensor(input)) {
        log.trace("Started inference");
        List<Tensor<?>> outputs =
                session
                    .runner()
                    .feed(inputLayerName, inputTensor)
                    .fetch(outputLayerName)
                    .run();

        log.trace("Finished inference");
        try (@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") Tensor<T> output = (Tensor<T>) outputs.get(0)) {
            return convertToResult(output);
        }
    }
}
```

And i try to learn this way:

```
session
    .runner()
    .feed(inputLayerName, inputTensor)
    .feed(outputLayerName, recognitionsTensor)
    .run();
```

But I need a fetch target.

What can I do to learn trainning the system?

Comment: You need to fetch the training operation, usually the result of a `minimize` call in an optimizer.

Comment: Old but maybe helpful: [tensorflowmodel](https://github.com/karlnicholas/tensorflowmodel)